# How to delete a line in Notepad using Replace?

Tags: windows, notepad++

I have very large log file , there are lot of useless stuff in that. So can anyone tell me how to delete a whole line if that particular line has matching string ?

for ex: i want to delete every line containing "W Useless:" string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "Mark" tab,

Type W Useless: on the Find section.

Check "Mark Line"

Click Find all and close.

Go to Search > Bookmark > Remove bookmarked lines.

Comment: question is about Notepad, not Notepad++

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**:

As mentioned by @*ratchet freak* replace `\r\n.*W Useless:.*\r\n` to `\r\n` on non-"dot matches all" mode

**OLD**:

This is a two steps solution:

First find `W Useless: .*$` and replace it with nothing using Regular Expression mode. This will leave empty lines.

Second, to clear those empty lines select extended mode and replace `\n\n` to `\n`. On windows line termination mode change `\r\n\r\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: or replace `\r\n.*W Useless:.*\r\n` to `\r\n` on *non*-"dot matches all" mode

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thanks for the suggestion. I upvoted it.

Comment: question is about Notepad, not Notepad++